# Laptop Screen Rotation Dell Inspiron 7348 / 7359 Kubuntu

Tags: display-rotation

I have a Dell Inspiron 7348 / 7359 that folds into a tablet mode. This works really well and the screen rotates etc in ubuntu. In kubuntu it does not. Any way to set this up? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this project works and can easily be installed.
https://github.com/donbowman/kde-auto-rotate